# Binding with derived function parameter

Tags: c++, std-function, stdbind

Is it possible to bind functions with derived parameters ? And if how ? I would like to be able to store function points to various functions that all have a similar signature, namely they take a class with input data and return a class with output values. But the different functions require and provide different parameters, hence I am trying to register functions that take derived message classes.

The following code works in part. I can register the function MathService::blank and I can later call it. But I cannot add MathService::add.

The error I get is:

> main.cpp:70:93: error: conversion from ‘std::_Bind_helper&)(RequestMessage&, ReplyMessage&), MathService&, const std::_Placeholder<1>&, const std::_Placeholder<2>&>::type {aka std::_Bind(MathService*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>)>}’ to non-scalar type ‘Service::serviceFunction_t {aka std::function}’ requested
>          serviceFunction_t fn = bind( methodPtr, objectPtr, placeholders::_1, placeholders::_2 );

```
#include <functional>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// base class for messages passed around
class BaseMessage
{
  public:
    virtual void print()
    {
      cout << "BaseMessage\n";
    }
};

// request message with data passed to the service
class RequestMessage : public BaseMessage
{
  public:
    RequestMessage( int a_, int b_ ) : a( a_ ), b( b_ ) {}
    int a;
    int b;
    void print()
    {
      cout << "RequestMessage a=" << a << " b=" << b << endl;
    }
};

// reply message with return values from the service
class ReplyMessage : public BaseMessage
{
  public:
    ReplyMessage() : sum( 0 ) {}
    int sum;
    void print()
    {
      cout << "ReplyMessage sum=" << sum << endl;
    }
};

// Example service provider
class MathService
{
  public:

    void blank( BaseMessage& request, BaseMessage& reply )
    {
      request.print();
      reply.print();
    }

    void add( RequestMessage& request, ReplyMessage& reply )
    {
      reply.sum = request.a + request.b;
    }
};


// Class manages services, register a new service with addService and call the service by name using call
class Service
{
  public:
    using serviceFunction_t = function<void ( BaseMessage&, BaseMessage& )>;

    template<class Method, class Obj>
    void addService( string name,  Method methodPtr, Obj objectPtr )
    {
      serviceFunction_t fn = bind( methodPtr, objectPtr, placeholders::_1, placeholders::_2 );

      pair< string, serviceFunction_t> entry( name, fn );
      mFunctionMap.insert( entry );
    }


    void call( const string& name, BaseMessage& request, BaseMessage& reply )
    {
      std::unordered_map<string, serviceFunction_t>::const_iterator it;
      it = mFunctionMap.find( name );

      if( it == mFunctionMap.end() ) {
        std::cout << "service not found: " << name << endl;
        return;
      }

      serviceFunction_t fn =  it->second;
      fn( request, reply );
    }

  private:
    unordered_map<string, serviceFunction_t> mFunctionMap;
};


int main()
{
  MathService math;
  Service service;

  // can add a service with BaseMessages
  service.addService( "blank", &MathService::blank, &math );


  //*****************************************************
  // PROBLEM is here !!
  // can not add a service with derived message types, this causes the bind call to fail in Service::addService()

  service.addService( "add", &MathService::add, &math );

  //*****************************************************

  // this works
  BaseMessage req1, rep1;
  service.call( "blank", req1, rep1 );

  // so does this
  RequestMessage req2( 1, 2 );
  ReplyMessage rep2;

  service.call( "blank", req2, rep2 );

  // this service is not registered
  service.call( "add", req2, rep2 );
```

}

Comment: Hmm... did you... perhaps... **try** it?

Comment: `do` is a reserved keyword

Comment: Also, change `std::placeholders_1` to `std::placeholders::_1`

Comment: Why are you posting fake code and asking a question which you can very well answer yourself?

Answer (score 0):

**1)** `do` is a reserved C++ keyword, so your code as-this will never compile

**2)** `std::placeholders_1` does not exist, you surely meant `std::placeholders::_1`

**3)** Once this is fixed, yes, [it compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d20f950bb4eddfa6).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the obvious. The previous example was intended as a concept of what I am trying to achieve. Maybe the extended example makes it more clear, any help appreciated.